# Settings do not work when running the program

Tags: vb.net

When I run the program from this path (\bin\Debug) it works fine, but when I export and run the program, the settings do not work

For example I have this button in the program

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If My.Settings.shcode.Contains("#") Then
        TextBox6.Text = My.Settings.shcode
        For Each item In My.Settings.adad
            ListBox1.Items.Add(item)
        Next
        Button1.Visible = False
        Button3.Visible = True
        Panel1.Visible = False
    Else
        TextBox6.Text = ""
        Button1.Visible = True
        Button3.Visible = False
        Panel1.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

The button works fine when running the program from the path (\bin\Debug), but it doesn't work when I export it
I tried to copy all the files in (\bin\Debug) to use it with another path but it didn't work too
What's the solution?

Comment: Did you use `My.Settings.Save()` somewhere before, to change the Settings content?  These are not saved in the Debug/Release folders (in `[Project].exe.config`), but in the current User's AppData folder and are version-specific.

Comment: yup i use save many times

Comment: Then the Settings are saved in the current User's AppData path (in a folder named after your executable), in a `user.config` file. Before deploying, you have to reset the settings to default values (calling `My.Settings.Reset()`). If you count on settings created and saved locally (in your machine), you won't find them when you install/move the executable in another machine.

Comment: Are the settings set to scope to Application or User?

Comment: User + I did another project with the same codes and work, I don’t know why

Comment: I reset the settings too. It didn't work. It looks like there was a conflict. I don't know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you move the program from its active path to somewhere else, its previous data will be saved only for that path. Therefore, that'll create another `Settings` for the application for the new location since the path is changed. That's why you won't able to get previous location's app saved data in new destination.

Instead, you can use creating and modifying registry to work globally on a computer.

Comment: To achieve registry creation and modification, you can see this thread I had recently answered: [Registry creation/modification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61402298/check-if-value-exists-within-registry-folder/61412796#61412796)